# Bash + Filter, drop whole sentences

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, grep

input (file):

```
This is something word1 delete
Another sentence word2d continuation
Should we remove this?
Let leave untouched
Also that is word1 let it stay
So this word1 delete also
word3 del this line should be also deleted
Please YDeTeLe me
```

filter (file):

```
word1 delete
this
word2d
word3 del
detele
```

desired output:

```
Let leave untouched  
Also this word1 let it stay
```

I saw some awk solutions where filter is connected with concrete record, but how to filter-out when strings in filter are not in specific place.

Shortly said, if line in filter file is substring of line in main (input) file, that line should be filtered-out.

I have python solution, easy to implement idea in python, still was curious can awk oneliner prove something **proof of concept**, like advantage of awk over python in some cases.

```
import codecs

lmyfilter = []
ffilter = codecs.open('filter', 'r', 'utf-8')
for line in ffilter:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    lmyfilter.append(line)
ffilter.close()

finput = codecs.open('input', 'r', 'utf-8')
for line in finput:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        letitpass = True
        for filteritem in lmyfilter:
            if filteritem.lower().strip('!"&\'()*,-./:;?<>[\]_{}«·»‑–—―‖‘’“”…′$#') in line.lower():
                letitpass = False
        if letitpass:
            print(line)
finput.close()
```

According to [Ed's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) falcon eye I'll have to add new requirements:
 * case sensitivity is off
 * solution need to be utf-8 based
 * punctuation marks from left or right of word to be ignored
 * awk now is not strictly required, but command line solution is

Comment: Hmm, not sure you should have left that comment, seems a bit presumptuous at best. Edit your question to show what you have tried so far and to clarify your requirements about what a "word" is in your domain, what characters constitute and/or separate "words", whether you're looking for string or repexp matching, whether it should be case sensitive or not, etc. and then show input/output that better represents all of the use cases. Signed, The Elves.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Main purpose for asking qustion is using it to filter twitter results via command line (I  use one twitter client made in ruby). I use that for my private personal purposes for news. I have implemented solution in python but! that is not fully command line which is I must admit advantage of awk over python. Sometimes for some task where can be awk oneliner goes 10-15 lines in python code. Will update now question with aditional requirements.

Comment: Ed, if I go with my own solution I'll  have to systematically read a lot for awk, and have time=money pressure for now. *nix is wide area

Comment: The `letitpass` variable in your Python code looks rather superfluous.  Just `continue` the loop and then `print` after that; the lines which triggered `continue` will not be printed.

Comment: Converting the filter file to a single regular expression will probably improve the runtime of your Python code significantly.

Comment: Yes I know, want to use boolean variable for later reusing in code.

Comment: Converting filter file to single regex is nice original idea!

Comment: @tripleee: to force a line break between two directly adjacent lines, you add two spaces to the end of a line. See [*Linebreaks* in the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#linebreaks).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I stand corrected; thanks. Still, this uses code formatting, where breaks are explicit anyway.

Comment: @tripleee: Yup, in a code block all whitespace is preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution for this kind of problem is

```
grep -vif filter input.txt
```

However, this also removes the line

> Also this word1 let it stay

which contains the pattern `this`. Do you want to discard each pattern after it is used?

Comment: No' patern stays for all lines. Looks efficient will check it later, tablet

Comment: here now, works perfectly. In input file 'this' in 5.th line was mistake, corrected with other string. For now as for simplicity and elegancy reasons your answer leads.

Comment: So there was a point, why wriiting ~10 lines in python, when this solution have few words only in one line.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{fs[$0]; next}
              {for(f in fs) if($0~f) next; print}' filter file    

Let leave untouched  
Also this word1 let it stay
```

Comment: That would fail if `other` or `this` was in `filter` instead of `word2d`.

Comment: The inner loop over the array of regular expressions bothered me enough to come up with a different answer.  I suppose the same idea could be refactored to an Awk script.

Answer (score 0):

If the filter file is well-maintained (ideally by some automation -- if done by hand, make sure there are no trailing spaces or DOS carriage returns, no typos, no comments, all regex specials are properly escaped, etc) you can simply transform it to a `sed` or `grep -E` script.

```
tr '\n' '|' <filter |
sed 's/\|$//;s/.*/(^|[^[:alnum:]])(&)([^[:alnum:]]|$)/' |
grep -Evif - input
```

The character class `[^[:alnum:]]` may not be exactly what you mean by "punctuation" but with this level of requirements, I leave it to you to work this out in more detail.  Maybe experiment with `\<` and `\>` instead.

The `tr` does the basic work of joining the filter expression by `|` characters on a single line.  The `sed` adds regex context around the basic filter expression to constrain it to (something like) isolated words. Then, we feed the generated expression to `grep -Ef -` with suitable options to remove any line with a match, case-insensitively.

Here is a refactoring of your Python code to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import codecs, re

with codecs.open('filterfile', 'r', 'utf-8') as ffilter:
    lmyfilter = [line.strip('\n') for line in ffilter]

puncsp = r'[][\s!"&\'()*,-./:;?<>\_{}«·»‑–—―‖‘’“”…′$#]'
regex = re.compile(r'(?:^|' + puncsp + r')(' + '|'.join(lmyfilter) +
    r')(?:' + puncsp + r'|$)', re.IGNORECASE + re.LOCALE + re.UNICODE)

with codecs.open('inputfile', 'r', 'utf-8') as finput:
    for line in finput:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        if regex.search(line):
            continue
        print(line)
```

Comment: checking solution, yes I maintain filter file with echo "newstring" >> filter

Comment: I don't get output with your current solution. With grep -Evif - words, words is input file?

Comment: Fixed to remove the final `|`  with `s/\|$//` -- if your `sed` uses a different syntax, maybe remove the backslash before the pipe.

Comment: sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2 on debian

Comment: Your solution works now, problem was trailing spaces in input file, even without adding s/\|$//. Tnx, your workable solution will be take in concern

Comment: Then put it in a comment.  It's not okay to have it in the question.  Anyway, you already backed out on your own initial deadline.  Accept whenever you like but don't make promises you can't keep.